# The uniqueness of the Einstein metric on $\mathbb CP^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Is the Fubini-Study metric the unique Einstein metric (up to scaling by a constant) on $\mathbb CP^n$? More restrictively, Is the Fubini-Study metric the unique Kahler-Einstein metric (up to scaling by a constant) on $\mathbb CP^n$?